# Is it possible to run a js function by means of a dropdown CSS menu?

Tags: javascript, css

## original post

Is it possible to run a js function by means of a dropdown CSS menu ?

I would realize a menu, looking like the habitual navigational ones, but aimed, instead, to run a different javascript function on each item, or, I think it's the same thing, to pass a different argument to a function and run it.

Is it practicable ? Googling, I pick the opposite (dropdown menu via js) ...

## addendum

Thanks to the advice provided by some courteous members, I have solved my problem, attaching an event handler to each item of the menu. Therefore I post here the code. Thanks again.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>

<style>
<!--http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp-->
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#myvar{
margin-top: 200px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function setVar(arg){
        document.getElementById("myvar").innerHTML = arg;
    }
</script>

<script>
    var x = 0;
</script>

</HEAD>

<BODY onLOad="setVar(x)">

<div class="dropdown">
  <span>menu</span>
  <div id = "menudd" class="dropdown-content">
    <p onClick="setVar(1)">item 1</p>
    <p onClick="setVar(2)">item 2</p>
    <p onClick="setVar(3)">item 3</p>
  </div>
</div>

<p onClick="setVar(3)">again 3</p>

<P id="myvar"></P>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: explain it more clearly

Comment: No, it's not possible to use CSS for that. But you can use a JS event handler to run a js function…

Comment: I don't think it's possible to run JavaScript using CSS, but you could add `javascript:doSomeJavaScriptHere()` as a link's `href` attribute.

Comment: Very broad but here is a tip. Each item has an ID. Build a script and create a function triggered by on click of each ID { do something}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by a "CSS menu". You don't create menus with CSS; you create them with HTML. You use CSS to style them and make them look menu-like.

All HTML-based web applications are based on attaching behaviors (implemented in JS) to HTML elements (such as buttons or menu items).

Attach an event handler for the `click` event to the HTML element that represents a particular menu item, and provide whatever function you want to execute.